# Парсинг json в Python3

Tags: python, json, requests

Задача получить json из веба и записать результат в report.json. В папке два файла: test2.py и report.json(пустой).

Код:

```
import requests
import json

r = requests.get('https://www.wikidata.org//w/api.php?action=query&format=json&meta=siteinfo&siprop=namespaces')
report = r.json()
print(report)
with open('report.json') as report:
    data = json.load(report)
    print(data)
```

Результат:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3
"/Volumes/My Files/Python/iikoBot/test2.py" {'batchcomplete':
'','query': {'namespaces': ...тело json... 'case': 'first-letter'}}}}

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Volumes/My 
Files/Python/iikoBot/test2.py", line 8, in <module>
        data = json.load(report)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py",
line 268, in load
        parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)   File
"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py",
line 319, in loads
        return _default_decoder.decode(s)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py",
line 339, in decode
        obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py",
line 357, in raw_decode
        raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1
(char 0)

    Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

у вас сразу несколько ошибок, по-моему:

1. `open('report.json')` - по умолчанию открывает файл на чтение, а не на запись
2. `json.load` читает JSON из файла, а вам надо писать

попробуйте вот так:

```
import requests
import json
import codecs

r = requests.get('https://www.wikidata.org//w/api.php?action=query&format=json&meta=siteinfo&siprop=namespaces')

with codecs.open('report.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json.dump(r.json(), f, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Comment: Спасио за оперативный ответ. Все получилось, но если в jsone есть русские слова, то они выводятся так: "Conception": "\u0414\u0430\u043d\u0438\u043b\u043e\u0432\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0439"

Comment: @DmitryC, я поправил ответ - попробуйте `codecs`  - это должно работать с Python 2 & 3

Comment: with codecs.open('report.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as report:
            data = json.dump(r.json(), report)
            print(data) не помогло :(

Comment: @DmitryC, вы можете дать URL с русским JSON для теста?

Comment: Решил так:
with open('report.json', 'w') as report:
            data = json.dump(r.json(), report, ensure_ascii=False)
            print(data)

Comment: @DmitryC, все верно, спасибо, я забыл, что `json.dump()`по умолчанию использует `ensure_ascii=True`. Я добавил вашу правку в ответ